# GCC 4.8 compilation error: cannot find the system header directory

Tags: compiling, gcc, cross-compilation

I'm trying to compile `GCC 4.8.3`. I have read the documentation carefully but I'm still unable to `cross compile` it for `64bit` system. I have also gone through [this guide](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org). But my requirement is to build `GCC` in `/tmp/xxx` directory. But the `--with-sysroot` & `--with-native-system-header-dir` flags are messing up the compilation. According to the documentation of `GCC`, I need to use `--with-sysroot` flag along with `--with-native-system-header-dir`.

`--with-system-header-dir` accepts a directory name where the header files are installed. In my case it is `${TOOLS_DIR}` and this should be an absolute path, which it is. And, `--with-sysroot` requires the root path of the folder where the compilation is being done. In my case, it is `${INSTALL_DIR}`.

```
INSTALL_DIR=/tmp/gcc-compile
TOOLS_DIR=${INSTALL_DIR}/tools
```

According to the `Linuxfromscratch` guide, I should create a folder on the root system of the host. But in order to do that I will need `sudo` permission which I don't have. So, I thought to compile `GCC` in a subdirectory rather than what was mentioned in the book (because all the users get read/write permission for `/tmp` directory).

Now, `GCC` stops with an error that it cannot find the system header directory. And, it tries to search in `/tmp/gcc-compile/tmp/gcc-compile/tools/include`, which is the **wrong path**.

The options that I have used are:

```
sed -i "s#/tools#${TOOLS_DIR}#g" ../gcc-4.8.3-pure64_specs-1.patch

patch -Np1 -i ../gcc-4.8.3-branch_update-1.patch
patch -Np1 -i ../gcc-4.8.3-pure64_specs-1.patch

printf '\n#undef STANDARD_STARTFILE_PREFIX_1\n#define STANDARD_STARTFILE_PREFIX_1 "%s/lib/"\n' "${TOOLS_DIR}" >> gcc/config/linux.h
printf '\n#undef STANDARD_STARTFILE_PREFIX_2\n#define STANDARD_STARTFILE_PREFIX_2 ""\n' >> gcc/config/linux.h

mkdir   "${BUILD_DIR}"  &&
cd      "${BUILD_DIR}"  &&

AR=ar LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath,${CROSS_DIR}/lib"   \
../configure --prefix=${CROSS_DIR}            \
             --build=${HOST}                  \
             --target=${TARGET}               \
             --host=${HOST}                   \
             --with-sysroot=${INSTALL_DIR}    \
             --with-local-prefix=${TOOLS_DIR} \
             --with-native-system-header-dir=${TOOLS_DIR}/include \
             --disable-nls                    \
             --disable-static                 \
             --enable-languages=c,c++         \
             --enable-__cxa_atexit            \
             --enable-threads=posix           \
             --disable-multilib               \
             --with-mpc=${CROSS_DIR}          \
             --with-mpfr=${CROSS_DIR}         \
             --with-gmp=${CROSS_DIR}          \
             --with-cloog=${CROSS_DIR}        \
             --with-isl=${CROSS_DIR}          \
             --with-system-zlib               \
             --enable-checking=release        \
             --enable-libstdcxx-time
```

While setting the options, I have written `${TOOLS_DIR}/include`, then why is it the `GCC` is trying to look into `${INSTALL_DIR}/${TOOLS_DIR}/include`? Can somebody direct me in the right direction?

**OUTPUT**

```
The directory that should contain system headers does not exist:
/tmp/gcc-compile/tmp/gcc-compile/tools/include
make[2]: *** [stmp-fixinc] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
rm gcc.pod
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/gcc-compile/cross-compile-tools/gcc-    final/gcc-4.8.3/gcc-build/gcc'
make[1]: *** [all-gcc] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/gcc-compile/cross-compile-tools/gcc-final/gcc-4.8.3/gcc-build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Please post output up to where `make` stopped with `*** Error [x] ...` line.

Answer (score 0):

The `--with-native-system-header-dir` option takes a *relative* path from the dir specified with the `--with-sysroot` option. So to make it work as intended, you need to pass `--with-sysroot=${INSTALL_DIR} --with-native-system-header-dir=tools/include`

Comment: I tried that too. It still gives me the same error.

Comment: Did you restart it all from scratch?

Comment: Yes, I cleaned up everything before trying again.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this with a soft link in sysroot.

```
if:
--with-systroot=${INSTALL_DIR}
--with-native-system-header-dir=${INSTALL_DIR}/include

then:
pushd ${INSTALL_DIR}
mkdir -p ./${INSTALL_DIR}
cd ./${INSTALL_DIR}
ln -s ../(number of dirs up)/include include
popd
```